# 2 drives 1 failing move my primary partition to the good drive that has my system reserved on it

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10

So my Disk1 is failing. S.M.A.R.T. said so. back up and replace or something. Yay. Not a problem I have a whole 1TB (not tablespoon) drive I'm not using. I'll go clone my whole drive over............. how and when did I do this, my system reserved is on disk0 and c: and restore on disk1...... there goes the most simple saves of all time. Without going and buying a third hdd what is the simplest way to scrap disk1 and keep everything that is installed like nothing happened for disk0?

[image: what my disk management looks like]

Comment: Alright, so in the end, I did a bunch. I gave system reserved a letter, so i can open it... In the folder options I let me see all hidden and systems files. I grabbed the Boot folder, and the bootsect.bak and bootmgr.exe and put them in a partition on the failing drive... unplugged the good drive went to repair boot options and did some rebuild and got the drive to run on its own... then i plugged in the good drive and ran AOMEI backup nd cloned the whole drive over to the good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made a comment on how I ended up fixing this. Let me first start with thanks to the commenters for their input. I did end up using AOMEI but nothing was easy, as I explained it would not be easy.

Starting off, I shrunk Disk1(Bad Disk) part1 about 500mb.
I created a partition on Disk1 named System Reserved. Exact size of the one on Disk0.

I then gave Disk0 System Reserved a drive letter to allow exploring it for some items I need.

I opened the view options of folder exploring so that I can see hidden and system files.

I opened Disk0 System Reserved and took a copy of Boot Folder, Bootmgr.exe, BootSect.bak

These were copied to the System Reserved Disk1(Bad Disk).

Changed Disk1 System Reserved to Active, Disk0 System Reserved to Inactive

I disconnected Disk0.

I rebuilt boot using commands in Advanced Repair Mode Cmd Prompt

Now Windows starts without Disk0 (good disk) all together. Very Slowly and with lots of read faults and junk. Good enough.

Now I have the ability to plug in good drive and clone bad to good.

Unplug bad drive... destroy bad drive...

Why was this so hard. Cloning a drive to another, the other needs to be empty.
Cloning a partition requires you pay for that software to unlock that feature.

The truth- I didn't want to have to reinstall jack. Is what I did recommended. No. I relied on my bad drive not giving out completely before I had a working copy of my contents. I did a lot of changes to partitions and disks that can break everything.

What I should have done... Gotten another drive and moved my windows partition to it...

Answer (score 0):

You can either clone the partition using a product like Macrium Reflect or you can image the drive and restore it to your new partition.

Comment: problem, the few products I've tried stipulate things like - I can't clone to the disk that has the system reserved on it, disk should be empty or you'll lose all data on disk. Then just doing the partition I have to pay on the one that can. So I was thinking... horrible as it may sound I may want to transfer the system reserved to disk that is failing... then I can clone the whole drive over. The drive works, I am using it right now for this. Its on its last legs and I am not losing everything.

Comment: AOMEI will clone a partition only and there appears to be a free version here: http://www.backup-utility.com/features/partition-volume-clone.html You can't clone TO the system partition, but you can clone to a different partition and change it to the system partition later. From your illustration above it doesn't look like you're cloning to the system partition anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You Should be careful when doing this part. Your Disk 0's most part is seen as unallocated so firstly you need to make them usable

1. Right click on the Unallocated part and create a simple partion give size for your partition.
2. create more partitons on 1 TB(Disk0) as you want. You may need to reinstall windows as the DISK1 is failing so make sure a partition is there for future use.
3. Copy over the data from DISK1 to newly created DISK0 partions using normal copy in windows

So your data is secured, make sure your new data's should be saved in new disk. you might need to install windows when disk1 failed to work, so early created partion's will help you. (Refer to windows installation [Link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/start-your-computer-from-a-windows-7-installation-disc-or-usb-flash-drive))